# Exposing an endpoint for a python program

Tags: python, python-requests, microservices

I want to expose an endpoint for a simple python program that takes in an input and manipulates it to return an output which would be the easiest approach for it.

example can be any simple python function such as:

```
def func(string):
    string= len (string)
    return tuple(int(string[i:string/2],6) for i in range (0,6,3)
```

It doesn't necessarily needs to be a web service. This is a microservice that can then be containerized

I need to be able to send in the i/p and receive an o/p in response communicating through the endpoint

Comment: this is way to broad a question that can have so many different answers or solutions

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by input and output, you mean normal data types like int, string, etc. and by end point you mean web services: You can read about [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/) . Flask allows you to create web services in python.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/end_point', methods=['GET'])
def hello():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        input = request.args.get('input', None)
        return func(input)

def func(string): string= len (string) return tuple(int(string[i:string/2],6) for i in range (0,6,3)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='8000', debug=True)
```

Now you can access your end point on `http:\\localhost:8000\end_point?input=your_input`

Comment: what if the input is a python object?

Comment: looking at the function in question, it seems as input will be string.